# How do I align certain lines of text to the right in JavaFX?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm using JavaFX to build a program wherein I need to display lines of text one after the other. Similarly to a messaging app such as WhatsApp, I need to align some lines of text to the right and others to the left, like this:

[image: An example of a WhatsApp conversation]

I first tried to use a TextArea, but I was only able to align all of the text towards one direction or the other. Additionally, it's a pain to add and remove text from a TextArea on the fly.

This led me to attempt to use a TextFlow instead, which makes use of Text nodes that I can control the individual attributes of, as well as add and remove as needed. While using the TextFlow however, I was still unable to align the nodes to the right of the Flow's area.
I tried to use both the setStyle() and setTextAlignment() methods, to no avail.

TL,DR: How can I control the attributes of Text nodes within a JavaFX TextFlow such that some nodes are aligned to the right, while others are aligned to the left?

Many thanks

Comment: The GridPane sounds like the perfect layout manager for you. You can offset the right aligned boxes by one or more columns to suit your needs. See here for GridPane info: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html Or using the Flow layout you could need to wrap the text inside another component that can align the text correctly with some padding on the left/right size.

Comment: If the sequence of text is truly a conversation like WhatsApp, then I would use a `ListView` with a custom `ListCell` implementation that aligns the group of text as needed. Each individual message would be its own item in the `ListView`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaFx ListView for chat application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193921/javafx-listview-for-chat-application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several alternatives to achieve this. One approach would be to use a `VBox` for the layout, and a `Label` wrapped in an `HBox` for the text:

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        VBox pane = new VBox();
    
        pane.setPrefWidth(300);
        pane.setSpacing(10);
        pane.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(20, 10, 20, 10));
    
        HBox text1 = createText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.", true);
        HBox text2 = createText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vel quam erat.", false);
    
        pane.getChildren().setAll(text1, text2);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(pane));

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private static HBox createText(String text, boolean right) {
        Label label = new Label(text);
        label.setWrapText(true);
        label.setMinWidth(200);
        label.setPrefWidth(200);
        label.setMaxWidth(200);
        label.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: " + (right ? "#DCF8C6;" : "white;") + "-fx-background-radius: 10;");
        HBox pane = new HBox(label);
        pane.setAlignment(right ? Pos.CENTER_RIGHT : Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        return pane;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

}
```

**Output:**

[image: Chat]